# Symmetric matrix with same diagonal elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A paper I was reading made the claim that the eigenvector of a symmetric matrix with same diagonal elements is :
$$i_n = {1, e^{jna}, e^{2jna}, ..., e^{j(N-1)na}}$$
$$ n =0, 1, 2 , ...N-1$$
$$a = \frac{2\pi}{N}$$
Why is this true?

I attach a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix is a [circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). It is well known circulant matrices are unitarily diagonalized by the [discrete fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). If you look at the discrete Fourier transform matrix, $i_n$ is the first column.